# Perl write excel to create charts with cells containing formulas in various worksheets

Tags: linux, excel, perl, xlsx, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to use Excel::Writer::XLSX module of perl and create charts with cells containing formulas?

Here is what I am doing:

1) Created an xlsx file with multiple worksheets - no issues

2) Created charts in one worksheet with constant values from other worksheets - no issues

3) Created a worksheet with cells containing formulas - no issues (I can see values in output xlsx)

4) Trying to create a chart from #3, its empty even though I can see the values as I noted above

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item 4 should work. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook   = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'chart_column.xlsx' );
my $worksheet1 = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $worksheet2 = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $bold       = $workbook->add_format( bold => 1 );

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
my $headings = [ 'Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2' ];
my $data = [
    [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7 ],
    [ 10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50 ],
    [ 30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30 ],
];

# Add the data to worksheet2.
$worksheet2->write( 'A1', $headings, $bold );
$worksheet2->write( 'A2', $data );


# Add formulas in worksheet1 to refer to the data in worksheet2.
for my $row (1 .. 7) {
    $worksheet1->write( $row -1, 0, '=Sheet2!A' . $row );
    $worksheet1->write( $row -1, 1, '=Sheet2!B' . $row );
    $worksheet1->write( $row -1, 2, '=Sheet2!C' . $row );
}


# Create a new chart object. In this case an embedded chart.
my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded => 1 );

# Configure the series.
$chart->add_series(
    name       => '=Sheet1!$B$1',
    categories => '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    values     => '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
);
$chart->add_series(
    name       => '=Sheet1!$C$1',
    categories => '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    values     => '=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7',
);

# Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
$worksheet1->insert_chart( 'D2', $chart, 25, 10 );

$workbook->close();

__END__
```

And here is the output:

[image]

So it looks like it works in Excel. However, it is possible that it won't work with some spreadsheet applications that don't calculate the results of formulas.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the example. Yes I am able to see the results now.